# CKEditor on custom page in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, activeadmin, ckeditor4.x

i got the following issue:

I want to add a form on a custom page (no model) to design an email for mailjet. I already got a custom page and a form with an CKEditor input and an input for the subject. But the subject field isn't shown on the page.

This is my code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Mail", namespace: :lku do

  def send_mail

  end

  content do
    panel 'Write mail' do

      semantic_form_for :mail, :url => "lku/send_mail", method: :post do |f|

        f.inputs do
          f.input :subject, :input_html => { :name => 'subject' }
        end
        f.inputs do

        f.input :text, as: :ckeditor, :input_html => { :name => 'text' }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the result:

[image: ckeditor without subject field]

When I add

```
f.actions
```

it looks like this

[image: just submit button]

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem without having ckeditor. Only the last element of form would display.

I don't know exactly what's going on, but it has something to do with how Arbre renders the content you generate inside the `content` block.

#### My solution is this

1. Transform the form content into .erb and move the form under `views/lku/mail/_mailform.html.erb`

   ```
   <%= semantic_form_for :mail do |f| %>
     <%= f.inputs do %>
       <%= f.input :subject %>
       <%= f.input :text %>
     <% end %>
     <%= f.actions %>
   <% end %>
   ```
2. Include the form in the page

   ```
   content do
     panel 'Write mail' do
       render partial: 'mailform'      
     end
   end
   ```

See if you can still mount the editor by using regular Rails form helpers - https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#form-helpers